# Send "Push Notification" when new video uploaded on specific channel in Roku scene graph

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I want to send a push notification when a new video is updated on a specific channel.

Is there available "Push Notification" in Roku scene graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are thinking about "Push Notifications" like on Android or iPhone then no - Roku does not have "Push Notifications".

Answer (score 0):

Roku OS doesn't provide you the push notifications feature. You have to rely on polling for your content.